# Getting this Error: .android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded

Tags: react-native, react-android

File /Users/MyName/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
  >   A problem occurred configuring project ':urbanairship-react-native'.
  >   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':urbanairship-react-native:_debugPublishCopy'.
  >   Could not find any version that matches com.facebook.react:react-native:[0.40,).
  >          Versions that do not match:
  >              0.20.1
  >              0.20.0
  >              0.19.1
  >              0.19.0
  >              0.18.0
  >              + 12 more
  >          Required by:
  >              Koopi Customer:urbanairship-react-native:unspecified
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 15.647 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the repositories file:

`touch ~/.android/repositories.cfg`